# How to express the following formula with quadratic form?

Tags: quadratic-forms

A and B are two constants, and $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are all binary vectors with the same length. How to express the following formula with quadratic form?

$$AB \vec{x}_1^T \vec{p}_1 \cdot \vec{x}_2^T \vec{p}_2\cdot\vec{x}_3^T \vec{p}_3-\frac{A(B+1)}{3}\vec{x}_1^T \vec{p}_1 \cdot \vec{x}_2^T \vec{p}_2\cdot\vec{x}_3^T\vec{p}_3[\vec{x}_1^T \vec{p}_1 + \vec{x}_2^T \vec{p}_2+\vec{x}_3^T\vec{p}_3]$$
An additional condition is $\vec{x}_i^T\vec{x}_i=1,i=1,2,3$.

Thanks very much.